# Toggle between two functions when button clicked.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following button which i am using as a toggle.

```
<button ng-click="togglefunction()">Toggle Data</button>
```

Here is the toggle part which should work

```
 $scope.toggleToolPanel = function () {
        // need to put below 2 functions here so that when user clicks 1st time, function 1 executes. when user clicks again, function 2 executes and so on. 
    };
```

These are 2 functions which should get executed alternatively inside the toggleFunction

```
 function function1(params) { 
                return '<span  >' + data + '</span>';
    }

function function2(params) { 
                return '<span  >' + data *100 + '</span>';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your controller:

```
$scope.firstFunction = false;
```

Then change your `toggleToolPanel` to the following:

```
$scope.toggleToolPanel = function() {
    $scope.firstFunction = !$scope.firstFunction;
    if($scope.firstFunction) {
        function1(params);
    } else {
        function2(params);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Toggle a class on the button element each time it's clicked.  See `classList.toggle`.  In your click event handler, use classList.contains to look for the presence of toggle.  If there do x, if not do y.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner code is attached below:

```
angular.module('mainModule', [])
         .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
           $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.isToggled = !$scope.isToggled;
        var params = $scope.isToggled;

                $scope.isToggled ? toggleIn(params) : toggleOut(params);

           };

           function toggleIn(params) {
        console.log(params);
       }

           function toggleOut(params) {
        console.log(params);
           }


         }]);

<body ng-app="mainModule">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="button" value="Toggle" ng-click="toggle()" />
</div>

</body>
```